# an object reference is required to access non-static field method or property c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, método, datatable

Tengo un metodo privado que me devuelve como resultante de la execucion de un data set.

Lo que deseo hacer es referenciar en este metodo un textBox que tengo en el boton principal d emi aplicacion de Windows Form. Para que el usuario cuando entre manualmente el 'Caption', este nuevo caption sea remplazado por el que esta ya.

El textBox lo puedo llamar sin problemas a patir del boton1_click pero no a partir de mi metodo.

Me aparece el error `an object reference is required to access non-static field method or property`
Aqui esta el metodo en el cual estoy tratando de llamar al textBox4.

Como podria hacer eso?

```
static private string GetMappingTable()
{
    string SourceID = "";

    var ds = GetMappingTable();
    foreach (DataTable dst in ds.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dst.Rows)
        {
             //Aqui me aparece el error
            if (textBox4.Text != "");
            var DataSourceId = ds.Tables["Table"]
            .Select("Caption = 'testUSers'")
            .Select(r => r["SourceID"]) 
            .Where(s => s != DBNull.Value)
            .Select(s => s.ToString()) 
            .FirstOrDefault();

            SourceID = DataSourceId;
             //Aqui me aparece el error
            SourceID = textBox4.Text;
        }
    }
    return SourceID;
}
```

Comment: Donde aparece el error? Cual objeto no funciona bien?

Comment: Hola, ya edite la pregunta y agregue donde me aparece el error

Comment: en que contexto tienes el metodo GetMappingTable() ? esta dentro del mismo winform o lo tienes dentro de un class separado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que has marcado tu método como `static`

```
static private string GetMappingTable()
```

Los métodos estáticos no tienen acceso a los campos de la instancia ya que no pertenecen a ninguna.

Simplemente quítale el keyword `static`

Comment: tienes toda la razon, no me di cuenta de eso muchas gracias!